# Facebook App Authentication with the PHP SDK

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I'm creating a Facebook app (as an iFrame inside FB) and trying to use the PHP SDK for authentication as well as any calls I need to make to FB.

I'm having some issues authenticating and can't figure out where I'm going wrong - it's either loading my site outside the FB chrome or inside the FB chrome but user is 0 and infinitely loops.

If I set this as my loginURL:

```
$fb->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $scope, 'redirect_uri' => $appUrl));
```

I get to the permissions page and then it will load my app outside the FB chrome. I get the state and code here, shouldn't the php sdk pick this up and ask for an access_token from this?

If I put response_type = 'token' like so:

```
$fb->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $scope, 'redirect_uri' => $appUrl, 'response_type' => 'token'));
```

Then it goes to my app inside the FB chrome but constantly loops and user = 0. Also, I get something like this in my url:

`#state=043f5cde02feb4e3a527bb2638d542d7&access_token=AAAEEdf0kQssBAGCz3TS8bZBN5CnOwi6gewBwjauEMpKTHRm2T8hZBpBYZAPJFWZCh5rjFQSgXtZCV0ZAIts9FxZBZCnZBv7OQ5DVURvpCAZBvrPlNpHDsPsLtB&expires_in=4313`

so the access_token is there, but I can't access it.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?